# wrap list items round div content

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to wrap list items around a div item (blue box).

My list items create a grid but I  want to center my logo into the grid and wrap the list items automaticly around it.

So the list items will show automaticly left and right above and under my logo.

Every list item has width:100px and height:100px and the blue box is width:300px and height:300px.

How can I solve this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcxEU.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display` and `float` you can do this *(basic with 5 elements)*: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dybFG/

```
ul {width:500px;}
ul, li, a, img {display:block;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;}
a  {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:auto;
background:gray;
text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;}
li:nth-child(2) {
  float:left;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  float:right;
}
li:nth-child(2) ,
li:nth-child(3) 
{
  line-height:300px;
}
li:nth-child(2) a,
li:nth-child(3) a
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300"/></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

16 links and one image : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeaqs/
if `nth-child` is not supported , use `class` in HTML